# How do I change the default date format in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

[order detail custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fl2w.png) In the WooCommerce order detail, the Date created is showing as 2023-03-03 and I would like to change this to format March 03, 2023.

There is also a custom field using Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce plugin ; pickup_date with the same format 2023-03-18 and I would like that changed to format March 18, 2023.

In the WordPress Settings > General the date format is Custom: F d, Y.  Timezone, Perth Australia.

I added some code (I got off the internet) for the functions.php in the child theme, I placed this at the end before ?> but it caused a critical error:

```
function WooCommerce_date_format() {
    return 'F d, Y';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_date_format', 'woocommerce_date_format' );
```

I have also tried changing the date format in Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce but this makes no difference.

I'm expecting to see the date format as March 18, 2023 (F d, Y)

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: I've managed to change the Order Date as I found where it was hard coded, but I'm still unable to change the custome option date format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't use the function woocommerce_date_format as it already exists inside WooCommerce. So, try to change the function name, and it should work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_date_format', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_date_format' );

function bbloomer_woocommerce_date_format() {
   return 'F d, Y';
}
```